# Printing from a BrowserView in electron 10

Tags: electron

In my electron app, a user can select one or more images for printing. To do this, I create a BrowserView which is not visible, load html into it and print it before destroying the view. This worked ok up to Electron 5. But after upgrading my app to electron 10, the printing still occurs but the image is broken (not visible). Any ideas?
Here is a sample of the HTML used to initialize my browser view:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <style>@media print {   @page { margin: 0; padding: 0;} html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; } html body *:not(.tempPrinterPaper) {display: none; visibility: hidden; z-index: -5000; } .tempPrinterPaper { display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; position: relative; page-break-after: always; page-break-inside: avoid; overflow: hidden; height: 100%; width: 100%; border: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; background-color: #FFFFFF; text-align: center; align-self: stretch; } .tempPrinterPaper img.tempPrinterPaperImage { display: flex; position: relative; height: auto; max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; z-index: 500000000000; visibility: visible; } }</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="tempPrinterPaper"><img class="tempPrinterPaperImage" src="C:\Users\igweo\OneDrive\Pictures\rts9nzl-e1526310385107.jpg" /></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is the code for printing:

```
    // now initialize browser window
            printerWindow = new remote.BrowserView( {webPreferences: {webSecurity: false}} );
            // load url
            printerWindow.webContents.loadURL('data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(printerHTML));
            // after contents have been loaded
            printerWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', function() {
                printerWindow.webContents.print({silent: false, printBackground: false}, function(res) {
                    // if printing is successful, show a notification
                    if (res) {
                        //let printNotification = new Notification('Image' + ((currentPrintList.length > 1) ? 's' : '') + ' successfully sent to printer', {icon: 'static/icons/logoFilledBlue.png'});
                        let printNotification = new Notification('Image' + ((currentPrintList.length > 1) ? 's' : '') + ' successfully sent to printer', {body: app_name});
                    }
                    // clean up print list
                    //currentPrintList.length = 0;
                    // after printing is done, destroy browser window
                    printerWindow.destroy();
                    // just to be sure :-) 
                    printerWindow = null;
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately in electron 10, the old ways no longer seem to work. What I have now done is to create a file called print.html, then write my html contents to the file and print it from the main process.

In app.js

```
    function showPrintDialog() {
     // build html string to be printed
     let printHTML = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><style>@media print {  @page { margin: 0; padding: 0;} }</style></head><body>HELLO WORLD</body></html>';
     // save file in the userdata directory
     let printFilePath = app.getPath('userData') + "\\print.html";
    // write to file using powershell (THIS IS ONLY FOR WINDOWS)
    let cmd = ['"' + printerHTML + '" | Set-Content -Path "' + printFilePath + '"'];
    let cx = cp.spawn('powershell.exe', cmd);
    // wait for completion
    cx.stdout.on('close', function(data) {
      (async function() {
         // invoke ipc function to display a dialog box and send the required parameters
        let printResult = await ipcRenderer.invoke('show-print-dialog', { printFilePath: printFilePath, successMessage: 'Successfully sent to printer'});
                    }) ();
            });
    }
```

Also, in app.js, we need a function to show notifications when printing is completed:

```
    ipcRenderer.on('show-notification', function(event, args) {
        // show a notification
        showNotification(args);
    });
```

Now, in our main.js, we will create a browserview with the written file and call the print command. When it is done, request a notification be shown.

```
    // show printing dialog and handle printing
    ipcMain.handle('show-print-dialog', async(event, args) => {
        // create a browser view
        try {
            // now initialize browser window
            let printerWindow = new BrowserView(  {webPreferences: {worldSafeExecuteJavaScript: true, contextIsolation: true}});
            // At this point, there should be a file called print.html in the local app path for the user
            // This should be to  C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Photo Viewer Classic\print.html
            printerWindow.webContents.loadURL(args.printFilePath);
            // after contents have been loaded
            printerWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', async function() {
                // show print dialog
                printerWindow.webContents.print({silent: false, printBackground: false}, function(res) {
                    // if printing is successful, res will return true
                    if (res) {
                        // show notification
                        event.sender.send('show-notification', args.successMessage);
                    }
                    // after printing is done, destroy browser window
                    printerWindow.destroy();
                    // just to be sure :-) 
                    printerWindow = null;
                });
            });
        } catch (e) { console.log(e); }
        // If failed, simply return false
    });
```